# Commutation or Anti-commutation of the corresponding imaginary units of the octonions and split-octonions

Tags: division-algebras, octonions

Given a general octonion x:

$\mathbb{O}$=$\mathbb{H}$+$\mathbb{H}$$L$ by

x=$x^1$+$x^2$i+$x^3$j+$x^4$k+$x^5$i$L$+$x^6$j$L$+$x^7$k$L$+$x^8$$L$

with $L^2$=-1,

and a general split-octonion x:

$\mathbb{O'}$=$\mathbb{H}$+$\mathbb{H}$$l$ by

x=$x^1$+$x^2$i+$x^3$j+$x^4$k+$x^5$i$l$+$x^6$j$l$+$x^7$k$l$+$x^8$$l$

with $l^2$=1,

does $L$ anti-commute or commute with $l$?

That is, do we have {$L$,$l$}=0 or do we have [$L$,$l$]=0?

How is the result proven?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to multiply elements of two different algebras.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that we can introduce the standard complex number "i" into an algebra (e.g., complexifying the quaternions or octonions) through complexification but are prohibited from introducing other complex numbers, such as $L$ or $l$ into algebras through a similar process.

Comment: Responding to your comment: You *can* introduce them through a similar process. Complexification is just tensoring with $\Bbb C$ over $\Bbb R$. You could just as easily tensor with the split complex numbers. I am not sure what you think the difference is between introducing $i$ versus introducing $L$, unless you mean introducing $L$ in addition to introducing $i$ and $j$, in which case you are simply tensoring with $\Bbb O$ over $\Bbb R$. If you want to adjoin both an $L$ and an $l$, though,you have to say what algebra contains both of them.

Comment: Thanks runway44. I understand now. I did mean introducing L in addition. Thanks.